# Modal Error Messages Displaying on Main page

Tags: 8

I have a page. Once i click on Button on that page. It opens jQuery Modal.

In that Modal Box. I'm rendering Form. I have put 1 fields test as **required true**.

Issue is when I click on Submit button. It closes Modal Box & showing errors on Main Page.

I need that when it clicks on Submit button. It will not close Modal Box & Display errors on Modal box instead of Main page.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is pretty old so hopefully you found another solution by now. Since I happened to come across this near the top of my Google search for a slightly different issue though...

In your form_alter hook for the modal, you will need to add something like this:

```
$form['#prefix'] = '<div id="modal-form">';
$form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
$form['status_messages'] = [
    '#type' => 'status_messages',
    '#weight' => -10,
];
```

Then the callback function for your form that closes the modal and such will need to look something like this:

```
$response = new AjaxResponse();

// If there are any form errors, re-display the form.
if ($form_state->hasAnyErrors()) {
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#modal-form', $form));
} else {
    //Close the modal.
    $command = new CloseModalDialogCommand();
    $response->addCommand($command);
}
return $response;
```

This will tell it to apply the error message to your #modal-form div instead of the form in the background.